# One simple spark program in scala : println out all the element in the RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote one simple spark in eclipse, I want to println out all the element in the RDD:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object WordCount {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit =  {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local");
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf);

  val data = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5));
  data.collect().foreach(println);

 sc.stop();

  }
}
```

And the result is like this:

```
 <console>:16: error: not found: value sc
         val data = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5));
```

I searched and tried more than three solutions but still cannot solve this. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where are you running your code ?

Comment: eclipse, i download the scala plugin.  for HelloWorld.scala, it works. but for this small spark program, there is an error

Comment: Have you read the Spark Programming guide ? What "solutions" did you try ?

Comment: ehh, maybe read it several weeks ago. I tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873500/scala-value-not-found

Comment: And I can run it successfully in spark-shell in linux. But in windows eclipse, it does not work.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to sound elitist, but you have to read the Spark Programming Guide again. You seem to be missing some basics. Spark works on Windows the same way it works on Linux based systems. I'm voting to close your question as it is too broad and lack of research, thus very low quality.

Comment: I did research and cannot solve it so I came to stackoverflow. Thanks for your answer. It seems you cannot solve this

Comment: You are kidding me, right ? How arrogant are you ? You don't even try to read the documentation and you are provoking me !

Comment: don't be so angry kid, I have solved this by myself and read the document again,but the solution has nothing to do with the document.Good luck to you!

Comment: @KevinZheng since you have solved this yourself please post an answer here to your own question to help others

Comment: *have solved this by myself* 
Great, can you post how you solved it and mark that as the accepted answer. This helps by 1) does not waste other potential answerer time, 2) when someone has the same issue they can find the answer here. Cheers.

Comment: @mattinbits @ mlk   I really appriacite your patience, I will share my way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact cause of whatever is troubling you since you don't mention how you set it all up, but you said that you can run it in spark-shell in linux so it's not about the code. It's most likely about the config and setup.

Perhaps my [short guide](https://github.com/slouc/spark-intro) can help you. It's minimalistic, but it's all I had to do in order to get the Spark "hello world" to run in Eclipse.

Comment: I really appriacite your patience and help, I will share my way to solve this. My solution here:  windows8, I use eclipse, 1. download the scala plugin 2.import the jar:spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop1.2.1.jar, but the plugin itself also import one library for spark, so I remove the plugin's jar for spark. 3.There is a version problem, I simply change the verson of scala from 2.11 to 2.10.  4. right click and choose run as/scala application. It finally works!  Thanks for you all!

Comment: No problem, I had it laying around anyway, I just shared a link :) glad you sorted it out!